# Couldn't read data from pList file. (Swift, iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, plist

Im trying to read and load data from a pList file. I have stored the data as NSArray in the file. But i couldn't read it. Below is the code that I have used.

```
    var documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    var path : NSString = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("imagesPList.pList")
    var data = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: path)
```

I took help from this [source](http://blog.kohjingyu.com/post/93103715225/persistence-in-swift-saving-data-with-a-plist)

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This.

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Property", ofType: "plist")
let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I also wanted to store the values in an Array. Could you help me with that, please?

Comment: you want to get array from dictionary key?

Comment: Yes. Thats exactly what i wanted to do. Thanks.

Comment: Its okay. I got it. 'imageNames.addObject(dict.valueForKey("Images")!)
'
Thanks much for your help

Comment: var arr:NSArray=dict["array"] as NSArray
        print(arr.objectAtIndex(0))

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let settings = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile:"Root.plist")
if let preferences = settings.objectForKey("PreferenceSpecifiers"){
//do something ...
}
```